# Python : How to project a 3D unstructured mesh to 2D?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, mesh, projection

From an unstructured mesh (`X,Y,Z + connectivity`), I wish to create a 2D array corresponding to Z projection (top-view) on plane(`X,Y`). 
At this end, I have used plot_trisurf from matplotlib (for 3D representation .. and it works) and then I have tried to use contourf(`X, Y, Z, zdir='z'`) to realize the projection. Unfortunately this last function seems to be only dedicated for structured mesh.

Is there a way to obtain (easily, with existing libraries) what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tricontour`. You can find [some examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/tricontour_demo.html) in the documentation. This is an example that they present there:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for. Now I am trying to export plot data  to a numpy array. I have seen buf = fig.canvas.tostring_rgb() +  np.fromstring(buf, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(nrows, ncols, 3) but things are not straightforward (rgb conversion to real value z + management of the canvas size and the number of pixels for each direction). Still a lot of work. Any idea to do it easily ?

Comment: @Patrick, that's a new question. Create a new question with a working example and I might help you there.

Comment: I did it in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617623/python-how-to-export-a-contourf-to-a-2d-array