# Python : How to export a contourf to a 2D array?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

From a complex 3D shape, I have obtained by tricontourf the equivalent [top view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXDmP.png) of my shape.

I wish now to export this result on a 2D array.
I have tried this :

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import skimage.draw as skdraw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [...]
y = [...]
z = [...]
levels = [....]

cs = plt.tricontourf(x, y, triangles, z, levels=levels)

image = np.zeros((100,100))

for i in range(len(cs.collections)):
    p = cs.collections[i].get_paths()[0]
    v = p.vertices
    x = v[:,0]
    y = v[:,1]
    z = cs.levels[i]

    # to see polygon at level i
    poly = Polygon([(i[0], i[1]) for i in zip(x,y)])
    x1, y1 = poly.exterior.xy
    plt.plot(x1,y1)
    plt.show()


    rr, cc = skdraw.polygon(x, y)
    image[rr, cc] = z

plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

but unfortunately, from contours vertices only one polygon is created by level (I think), generated at the end [an incorrect projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMrwU.png) of my contourf in my 2D array.

Do you have an idea to correctly represent contourf in a 2D array ?

Comment: Do yo want to represent your contours as numbers in a rectangular array? Assigning NaNs to values outside your region?

Comment: If I remember correctly, `cs.collections[i].get_paths()` returns a *list* of contour line segments corresponding to level `i`. This is in agreement with your referencing only `...get_paths()[0]`. You probably have to loop `for path in ...get_paths()` and plot each path independently. But watch out: there can be open contour lines, so using `Polygon` like that might not be correct (and this might explain your spurious lines across the figure). I suggest using a simple example function with simple contour lines to get a grasp of how these things are done under the hood.

Comment: @nicoguaro : I can't assign value outside my region 'cause I don't know it a priori.

Comment: @Andreas : It's getting better (see below)

Answer (score 0):

Considering a inner loop with **for path in ...get_paths()** as suggested by Andreas, things are better ... but **not completely fixed**.
My code is now :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

x = [...]
y = [...]
z = [...]
levels = [....]
...

cs = plt.tricontourf(x, y, triangles, z, levels=levels)

nbpixels = 1024
image = np.zeros((nbpixels,nbpixels))
pixel_size = 0.15 # relation between a pixel and its physical size

for i,collection in enumerate(cs.collections):
    z = cs.levels[i]
    for path in collection.get_paths():
        verts = path.to_polygons()
        for v in verts:
            v = v/pixel_size+0.5*nbpixels # to centered and convert vertices in physical space to image pixels 
            poly = np.array([v], dtype=np.int32) # dtype integer is necessary for the next instruction
            cv2.fillPoly( image, poly, z )
```

The final image is not so far from the original one (retunred by plt.contourf).

Unfortunately, some empty little spaces still remains in the final image.[(see contourf and final image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHzpc.png)

**Is path.to_polygons() responsible for that ? (considering only array with size > 2 to build polygons, ignoring 'crossed' polygons and passing through isolated single pixels ??).**